# Why notification PendingIntent doesn't work?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I have a notification and a "Stop" button on it. The `PendingIntent` of this button refers to `BackgroundTaskService's` inner class `NotificationReceiver`. But when I click the "Stop" button nothing happens. What is wrong?

**NotificationsLab class:**

```
class NotificationsLab{
    /*...Some constructors, variables and other stuff here...*/

    public Notification createNotification(UUID taskId){
        Intent intent= new Intent(mContext, BackgroundTaskService.NotificationsReceiver.class);
        intent.setAction(BackgroundTaskService.CANCEL_TASK_ACTION);
        intent.putExtra(TASK_ID, taskId);
        PendingIntent cancelPendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0, intent, 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext, CHANNEL_ID)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_file_gray_classic_24dp, "Stop",
                        cancelPendingIntent)
                .setProgress(100, 0, false);
        return builder.build();
    }
}
```

**BackgroundTaskService class:**

```
class BackgroundTaskService extends Service{
    private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new NotificationReceiver();
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(CANCEL_TASK_ACTION);
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
        return mIBinder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(CANCEL_TASK_ACTION);
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(CANCEL_TASK_ACTION);
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
    public static class NotificationsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.d("TAG", "You will never see this message!!!");
        }
    }
}
```

So, the message that the `Log.d` should print will never appear. What can I do with it?

Comment: @EliasFazel but why, Notification receiver is a BroadcastReceiver...

Comment: @EliasFazel I changed PendingIntent.getBroadcast to PendingIntent.getService and it still doesn't work

Comment: @EliasFazel yes. Everything within the service works excluding the broadcast receiver. Also I copied this code from my working project and here it doesn't work.

Comment: You should accept your answer by clicking the green checkmark next to your answer. That will get the question off the list of unanswered questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I forgot to add my `BroadcastReceiver` to the manifest.

Just added `<receiver android:name=".services.BackgroundTaskService$NotificationsReceiver"/>` to the Manifest